# Postgis Point Data type is not persisting into DB

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, postgis, hibernate-spatial

When I try to persist Point datatype to postgres DB it is failing with error
**org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "pointColumn" is of type point but expression is of type geometry**

Here is my pojo snappit

```
@Type(type="org.hibernate.spatial.GeometryType")
@Column(columnDefinition="Point", nullable = true)
private Point pointColumn;
```

Here is my driver and dialect properties

> driverClass=org.postgresql.Driver
>
> dialect=org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisDialect

Here is my spatial version details

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-spatial</artifactId>
   <version>4.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.vividsolutions</groupId>
   <artifactId>jts</artifactId>
   <version>1.13</version>
</dependency>
```

Even I have registered GeometryType to jdbc Configuration as below

```
GeometryType geometryType = new GeometryType();
configuration.registerTypeOverride(geometryType);
```

Even this issue is true for Polygon,LineString,Point,MultiPoint,MultiPolygon...

Am I missing any configuration or it is expected behaviour from Geometry Type implementation ?

Answer (score 2):

PosgreSQL has some [in-built geometry support](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-geometric.html). You're trying to use the type `point` from the base pg, you need to change that to `geometry` as it is a geometry representing a point in PostGIS.

Comment: Jakub,I have changed my java type to Geometry instead of Point and My DB type is still  remaining as Point.But still when I persist, I got same error.

Comment: I dont understand when to use Postgis and Postgres dialect.I want to use Point,Polygon,LineSegment types.As Spatial provided GemotryType then I used Postgis dileact ,  which has GemotryType definitions.

Comment: @SunilKumar Have you tried changing the db column to `geometry`?

Comment: After changing DB type to geometry it is working.I dont understand What is the use of other types like Point,Polygon,LineString.....Can you clarify,Gemotry type is Postgis type right ? And Point is of base postgres type ?

Comment: Also What if DB is not accessible to me and the types are Point,Polygon...And How to work with such types in reverse engineering process.

Comment: @SunilKumar `Geometry` and `Point` are different types. `Geometry` is only in PostGIS and that's what you should use. Please ask a new question for the rest of your questions and mark this one as accepted if the problem with storing was solved. I don't work with Java so I don't even know that much.

Answer (score 0):

The right geometry classes to use are inside of `com.vividsolutions.jts.geom` package. H-S maps JTS geometries to DB native structure, so, don't use posgis classes. This is due to make applications DB independent (one of the main points of JPA API).

See [H-S overview](http://www.hibernatespatial.org/):

> Hibernate Spatial uses the Java Topology Suite (JTS) as its geometry
>   model. JTS is an implementation of the OpenGIS Simple Features Implementation Specification for SQLv. 1.1 (SFS). This specification is implemented in most RDBMS with spatial data support. It is also a direct precursor to a precursor to SQL/MM Part 3: Spatial (ISO/IEC 13249-3).

This is a [gvNIX](http://www.gvnix.org/en/index.html) [sample application](https://github.com/DISID/gvnix-samples/tree/master/quickstart-geo-app) ([on-line demo](http://geo-gvnix.rhcloud.com/login)) which handles geometries types. This is a [JPA entity](https://github.com/DISID/gvnix-samples/blob/master/quickstart-geo-app/src/main/java/com/springsource/petclinic/domain/Owner.java) which declares 3 geometry properties:

```
...
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.LineString;
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Point;
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Polygon;
...
...
public class Owner extends AbstractPerson {

    @Type(type = "org.hibernate.spatial.GeometryType")
    private Point location;

    @Type(type = "org.hibernate.spatial.GeometryType")
    private LineString distance;

    @Type(type = "org.hibernate.spatial.GeometryType")
    private Polygon area;
}
```

Good luck!!

Comment: @ Jmvivo : Even I have created same class structure and My Database have Point as column type.And When I try to persist it in DB through hibernate it is failing to convert( exception in description).What is your DB type ?,Is it working while persisting into DB ?

Comment: As you can see in on-line demo, persistence works as expected. If you follow the instructions in project main page (_Run from Git_ section), you can get it working, so you can compare it with your project.